# Dynamic source in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

Please, I need to create a dynamic source in ADF, I have a flow and I need to apply it to multiple files from a directory. Basically, I need that the source take all the files from a specific directory an run each one across the flow, and at the sink, I need one file from each one that take in the source, according to the file name.

Can someone help me with this, please?

I only know how to make a source with one specific file and no with multiple files at the same time, so, I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to copy all the files from the folder to sink with the same filename, you can use wildcard file path in copy activity. Below is the detailed approach.
- Take the copy activity and select the source dataset.
- In source settings of copy activity, Select **Wildcard filepath** as file path type.

[image]

- In sink settings, select the copy behavior as `Preserve Hierarchy`. This will make sure the structure of source and sink file systems remain same.

[image]

- When the pipeline is run, all the files from the single folder is copied to sink folder.

**Reference:** Refer the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#copy-activity-properties)  on copy activity properties in ADF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is not what I want to do, I need to call all the files from a specific folder and run each one into a data flow that I have,

Comment: You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74729634/19986107). Here you can use only the child pipeline, which takes files from a folder and passes it to dataflow activity which is in for-each activity.

Comment: Hey, I think it works, but I have something wrong in my data flow, I think that I have and specific source and not the result of the pipeline as a source.

Do you know how could I fix this?

Comment: Give the specific folder name directly, instead of passing it as a parameter value.

Comment: I have this as a wildcard path in my source dataset, but I don´t know if it´s right: 
toString(like($Filename, 'AC'))